# In app billing: consume and purchase item then update inventory, caching?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

### Problem

I'm trying to implement in app billing v3, everything is working pretty nice except for one thing. After consuming or purchasing an item I do a request call to update the inventory. But the result always yields the old inventory and not the new one, with the added or removed item.

This could be expected behavior and I do have a workaround, but it's still pretty annoying.

### Workaround

My work around exists out of a special "handler/wrapper" for in-app-billing. This "handler" has a simple life cycle.

**1. create (new call):** Creates a new `IabHelper` object and does some magic with the publickey

**2. startUp:** calls the `startSetup` method from the `IabHelper` and sets a flag when successful. If successful it makes a update inventory call.

**3. close:** despose the IabHelper object

The handler implements the `onQueryInventoryFinished` method, when this method is called and the result is success a local Inventory object is updated using the Inventory argument given with this method.

So basically the handler I made has two fields a Inventory and flag for successful setup. The handler also has a custom made interface for callbacks to an activity for example.

There are two more methods: `buy and consume`.

After successfully buying or consuming an item I would like to update the current inventory, but this does not work as said before.

My workaround: Remove or add the purchases manually from the local Inventory object. (this should be done in the buy or consume method.)

### Better method?

Is there a better "more acceptable" way of doing this?

Comment: Can confirm this behavior. And I would even say it is a Bug in Billing 3 API.